# Android ClassNotFoundException in my googleplay dev console

Tags: android

100% stumped here.  I do not even know where to begin.  Could this be something foobar on the users phone?  These 2 errors are from the same type of phone and 1 happens on the startup screen (Splash) and the other is the screen after the splash (MainActivity)

Error Title in the dev console :

```
ClassNotFoundException in dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass
```

Type of phone that is giving me the error :

```
DROID RAZR (cdma_spyder)
```

My Log Error 1 :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{joseph.lubonty.librarysmite11/joseph.lubonty.librarysmite11.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "joseph.lubonty.librarysmite11.MainActivity" on path: /mnt/asec/joseph.lubonty.librarysmite11-2/pkg.apk
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2060)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2174)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:141)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1267)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5059)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "joseph.lubonty.librarysmite11.MainActivity" on path: /mnt/asec/joseph.lubonty.librarysmite11-2/pkg.apk
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2051)
... 11 more
```

My Log Error 2 :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{joseph.lubonty.librarysmite11/joseph.lubonty.librarysmite11.Splash}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "joseph.lubonty.librarysmite11.Splash" on path: /mnt/asec/joseph.lubonty.librarysmite11-2/pkg.apk
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2060)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2174)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:141)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1267)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5059)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "joseph.lubonty.librarysmite11.Splash" on path: /mnt/asec/joseph.lubonty.librarysmite11-2/pkg.apk
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2051)
... 11 more
```

My manifest :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="joseph.lubonty.librarysmite11"
android:installLocation="preferExternal"
android:versionCode="22"
android:versionName="3.0" >

<compatible-screens>

    <!-- all normal size screens -->
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />

    <!-- all large size screens -->
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />

    <!-- all xlarge size screens -->
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="xlarge" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="xlarge" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="xlarge" />

    <!-- Special case for Nexus 7 -->
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="213"
        android:screenSize="large" />

    <!-- Special case for HTC One -->
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="480"
        android:screenSize="large" />

    <!-- Special case for Android DNA -->
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="480"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
</compatible-screens>

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/b_promo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:logo="@drawable/i_topbarimage1"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".GodStatComparison"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".JungleTimers"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".JungleInfoTablet"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".JungleTimersTablet"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".TopPlayers"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: I've had a couple of these before. They happened so rarely that I chalked it up to a very rare Android bug, possibly in a custom ROM.